# Stream Heart Pulse from Apple Watch OS 2

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos-2

Is it possible for a WatchOS2 App to get notified of each pulse from the heartbeat sensors?

Comment: I would expect the answer to be no since you'll not be reading the CCD data from the watch case but instead calling an API to tap into the processed data that is interpreted into a rate. Have you a specific question about the API or is this more about the hardware capabilities? (Basically, describe your problem more and what you've done to solve it).

Comment: Thanks, I market this question as duplicate - I basically wanted to build a realtime pulse monitor.